# Why is the content setter only applied to the last control?

Tags: c#, wpf

The following code will create tow buttons but the style will only be applied to the second I know I can use a template instead but I was wondering why this setup does not work?

```
   <Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="help"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Setter.Value> 
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></Button>


</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot (or at least should not) use a UI element in a `Setter`, because a UI element can only exist in one place in a visual tree.  That is to say: a UI element may only have one parent element.  Try setting the content to some non-UI value, like a simple string, and let WPF apply a data template for you:

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="help" />
```

If you want to specify complex UI content, set a `ContentTemplate` instead; that will allow you to use a `DataTemplate` to build up a common visual tree.

Note, however, that it is unusual to set `Content` on a button setter; the content typically *varies* from button to button, whereas styles are meant to set property values that should be common across control instances.

Answer (score 3):

`Style` is shared so there is only one instance of `Grid` and since `Visual` can have only one parent it will be visible in the last place where you use it. You can disable sharing for `Style`

```
<Style ... x:Shared="False">
```

[x:Shared Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx)

> When set to false, modifies WPF resource-retrieval behavior so that requests for the attributed resource create a new instance for each request instead of sharing the same instance for all requests.

Comment: Is it better to use a template or set the shared attribute to false? Or does  this have the same performance affect?

Comment: This is just another way of doing things but personally where  I can I would chose template. If you can avoid it you shouldn't use visual in style setter

Comment: Agreed, if you want to stick with the recommended practices for WPF, use templates.  In nearly a decade of WPF development, I have never found it necessary to use `x:Shared`, and going that route is basically a way of working *around* the rules and best practices.  That said, it's a useful thing to know about.

Comment: Thanks everyone for clearing this up. Both of you have been very helpful.